# Removing border from Filemaker Web Viewer to Create Image Slider

Tags: html, filemaker

Hi there I am trying my hand at inserting custom HTML into the Filemaker Web Viewer but am having a trouble removing the border from the web viewer when I add the HTML Doctype tag to the code.  The border is removed if I take out the tag but without the tag the slideshow won't function.  Any ideas?

```
    "data:text/html,

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>

    <head>

    <style>

    #slideshow { 
    margin: 0; 
    position: absolute; 
    width: 250px; 
    height: 250px; 
    padding: 0;  
    overflow:hidden;
    }

    #slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    right: 0px; 
    overflow:hidden;
    bottom: 0px; 
    }

    </style>

    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/236154657/CVI%20Slideshow.js'></script>


    </head>


    <body style='border=0;margin=0;overflow:hidden'>

    <div id='slideshow'>

    <div>
    <img src= 'http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5224/5658667829_2bb7d42a9c_m.jpg'  style='width:100%; height:100%;'>
    </div>

    <div>
    <img src= 'http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5230/5638093881_a791e4f819_m.jpg'  style='width:100%; height:100%;'>
    </div>

    </div>


    </body>

    </html>

    "
```

Comment: Are referring to the border around the picture of the dog or a different border? When I insert your code into a data viewer the only boarder I see is around the pic of the dog which seems to be a part of the dog image itself.

Comment: Hi @Chris Schmitz.  No not the border on the dog.  In Filemaker when you embed this code inside of a web viewer with the HTML Doctype tag it displays a 10px top and left white border.  Here is a screenshot.  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/236154657/Border-Screenshot.png

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz I have found but a few articles on how to remove it but none of them require the HTML Doc tag which I need because my image slideshow won't work without it.  When I take the tag out the border is removed.  But when I insert the tag it seems to be creating some sort of wireframe.

Comment: Ooooh! You're talking about the white border that's keeping the image from being at the very top and left of the web viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you're running into isn't filemaker, it's the web code itself.

The HTML and body tags get some default styling applied to them by the web browser. If you take your code and write it out in just a regular html file you can see the padding as well.

Try adding this to your style tag:

```
html,body{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

This will tell the web page that your html and body tag need to take up the entire browser window (the height and width rules) and that they should have no padding or margins. This will make sure your image tag is flush against the boundaries of the web viewer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You are awesome.  It worked! I have been searching the web for hours.  I'm still learning my way around HTML and CSS.  I've done mostly database development up until now and I don't know what I would do without people like you and Stackoverflow.  Thanks again!

Comment: No problem :) I'm glad it worked for you. You've probably been to one or all of these sites, but just in case here are a list of website you may want to check out as far as learning about web development: http://www.w3schools.com/ https://www.codeschool.com/  http://css-tricks.com/ There are plenty of others, but these are good starting points.